# Windows Batch: Reading/Searching a File Whilst it is Being Edited?

Tags: windows, batch-file, search

I can't seem to find any information on what happens if you read/search a file using a Windows Batch Script when the file still needs to be editable at the same time (eg an application log file bring written to in real time).

Does the batch file lock the file you are reading/searching?

Does it read the file contents from the particular datetime you accessed it only ignoring any subsequent edits. In particular, I'm interested in the answer for using for /f or findstr or find.

Thanks

Comment: You could test it. Btw. What is `edit`? `edit` depends on the program you are using for editing and that results in different behaviour depending of that program

Comment: My main reason for asking is to read an applications log file, which is bring written to (edited) in realtime, not by an individual user but by the application backend itself. I'm just interested in searching it say every 15mins

Comment: As I'm understand, your application appends lines to the file. That could be done by accessing the file with (read/write) shared or exclusive access, but as said that depends on your application, but very probably it uses shared mode

Comment: I'm using a work around as I don't want to risk it affecting Production. I'm copying the 50 log files (esp as they rename/shuffle) to a temp directory & searching them there. Just thought there would be some documentation.